# Querying Big Query repeated mode

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm storing an array of values in bigquery table.

```
Table Name : Embedding
Table Schema :

    {
        {
            field_name:"description",
            type:"string",
            mode:"nullable"
        },
        {
            field_name:"embedding",
            type:"float",
            mode:"repeated"       
        }
    }
```

I can insert data perfectly. In webUI of bigquery, the preview data is also shown properly. But when I query the data, I get the following output

SQL query - `select * from dataset.Embedding;`

Output -

```
[["0.3","hello new york"],["0.5","hello new york"],["0.1","hello new york"],["0.9","hello new york"],["0.3","hello new york"],["0.2","hello new york"],......,["0.8","hello new york"]]
```

The values are repeated along with the description instead of getting an array of values like `["0.3","0.5","0.1","0.9","0.3",...,"0.8"]`.

I tried `unnest` functionality also. But no luck.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: You would get that result if the data is stored as multiple rows.  You don't appear to be using arrays to store the numbers.  Also, your query won't return that result, because the columns are in the wrong order.

Comment: So @GordonLinoff, what is the correct way to store and access array in bigquery?

Comment: . . I am only pointing out that you have multiple rows of data, if the query is returning multiple rows.

Comment: @bigbounty in BigQuery you would want to add a record, with a repeated float inside it I believe. 

Something like the following:
`
[
  {
     "name": "description",
     "type": "STRING",
     "mode": "REQUIRED"
  },
  
  {
        "name": "embedding",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "value",
                "type": "FLOAT",
                "mode": "REPEATED"
            }
        ]
  }
]
`

Comment: `the preview data is also shown properly` - can you show what it shows you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT em FROM dataset.Embedding AS E cross join E.embedding AS em
```

This cross joins the contents of the array with the table so you can actually query it as if they were scalar values in the table.

Comment: I want to avoid join. I'm looking for alternative ways

Comment: It takes too much time. I'll be joining millions of rows

Comment: No, it doesn't take too much time. BigQuery works on these tasks in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then I think `array_agg` may help you here.

Something like:

```
SELECT description, ARRAY_AGG(embedding) AS embedding
FROM dataset.Embedding
GROUP BY 1
```

If `description` is not unique, then you may want to add a primary key style column.